# How to run lerna sequentially?

Tags: sequential, lerna

**Goal**

Wish to know how with **[Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/)** to run packages in sequential mode.

**Approach**

This is **learn.json** with its **packages** declaration:

```
{
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "npmClientArgs": [
    "--registry",
    "https://npm.foo.com"
  ],
  "command": {
    "publish": {
      "ignoreChanges": [
        "**/.spec.*",
        "**/*.md",
        "**/tsconfig*.*"
      ],
      "registry": "https://npm.foo.com"
    }
  },
  "packages": [
    "packages/commands/*",
    "packages/specs/*",
    "packages/support/*",
    "packages/tasks/*",
    "packages/tools/*"
  ],
  "version": "independent"
}
```

And in **package.json**, the following is a sampling of its scripts making `lerna run` requests:

```
    "audit": "lerna run audit --stream",
    "build": "lerna run build --stream",
    "clean": "lerna clean",
    "postinstall": "lerna bootstrap",
    "upgrade": "lerna run npm:upgrade --stream",
    "test": "lerna run coverage --stream"
```

The goal is to modify the **package.json script "test"** so that **lerna runs each of the packages' test sequentially** over each of the packages and **not in parallel**.

And if possible, run tests in a **specific order**.

How should this **`"test"`** script be modified?:

```
    "test": "lerna run test --stream"
```

**`lerna run`** does have a command option **`--parallel`**, however, I am experiencing that without this option set, execution is happening asynchronously (parallel):

```
--parallel          Run script with unlimited concurrency, streaming prefixed output.
```

Comment: `lerna run test --stream` should run it sequentially. What behaviour are you observing?

Comment: @Maneet this is not true. `--stream` just streams the output of a package immediately, so that you can see the output of different packages while running lerna.

Comment: That sounds right @TimHilt. In the past, I have observed that `lerna` runs the commands in the correct topological order when the `--parallel` flag is not used. So, that still doesn't guarantee sequential execution since multiple packages may have the same priority in the topological order and hence, may run in parallel. Don't have an answer for the OP currently.

Comment: `--concurrency` flag can solve this. [Ref](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/main/commands/exec#options)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lerna run --concurrency 1`

```
Global Options:
      --concurrency    How many processes to use when lerna parallelizes tasks.      [number] [default: 10]
```